# Why does my phonegap build android command not work?

Tags: android, cordova, command

i am new to phonegap 3 and android development.

i tried the command "phonegap build android" and get:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.
fs.js:427
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\Michael\.cordova\lib\android\
cordova\3.1.0\VERSION'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at Object.exports.createProject (C:\Users\Michael\.cordova\lib\android\cordo
va\3.1.0\bin\lib\create.js:116:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michael\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\b
in\create:34:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Comment: Please try running `phonegap build android -d` and paste the output here - the `-d` flag will give you more debug information. Also, what is your `pwd` say? Sometimes there are problems if your path has spaces or special characters in it.

Comment: the debug flag doesnt output anything, the return is the same error than in the first post. I am using windows so echo %cd% says C:\development\projects\hello

Answer (score 3):

I simply add an empty file named as VERSION:

```
C:\Users\myuser\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\VERSION
```

after, I wrote this text inside it:

```
3.1.0
```

after, run phonegap again:

```
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it did help but the error message is now different.    [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of tricky This is the sequence I have to go through.

1. run a clean in eclipse (Project Menu)
2. sudo phonegap build android (cordova if that is what you are using)
3. then you have to reapply the read write permissions to the whole folder (this step may not be needed depending on your permissions)
4. then in eclipse run refresh on the project
5. then build.
6. Run

Comment: yes, i am using pure commandline like the phonegap tutorial says :)

Comment: sorry. have you made sure you have all read write permissions? when you do a "phonegap platform ls" is Android listed as installed?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest as a bare minimum first step you should check via the command line that the following commands return a response that shows they are working correctly. They are all required. Ant - http://ant.apache.org/

Java -http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html

android - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

In command line type the following to validate they work

Ant

java

android

Make sure you have node.js installed (http://nodejs.org/)
Also make sure you look at you PATH file and that everything is correct there.

As I say that's the basics (once you have stuff installed)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install latest cordova. Maybe it will help:

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

(also you will need node.js installed)

Comment: why not the latest phonegap? `$ sudo npm install -g phonegap`

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Because he gets error on cordova path.

Comment: i am using phonegap and already installed the latest one because its the first time i installed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have removed android platform and added again.

cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android

then,
cordova prepare android

is done without errors